# Dismiss iOS Keyboard before finger reaches it

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, dismiss

I am using a UIScrollView with dismiss set to Interactive. Hence when keyboard is visible and I drag my finger down, as soon as my finger reaches the keyboard, the keyboard will go down at the same pace than my finger.

How can I have the keyboard going down earlier, ie when my finger is already 40 pixels above it ?

Comment: You could dismiss the keyboard as soon as the UIScrollView begins scrolling down?

Comment: But how to dismiss the keyboard interactively, ie at the same pace than my finger ? As I am not aware of any function to position the keyboard.